# Unable to cast object of type System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object] to type System.Collections.Generic.IList[ShortCodeList]

Tags: c#, generics

The BindingProperties returns the Type T. The result the linq query brings at runtime is `System.Collections.Generic.IList[ShortCodeList]` but when I try to type cast it with IList T>, it returns:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[ModelAccessLayer.Model.ShortCodeList]'

```
    private IList<T> GetResultSetConvertedToList<T>(IList<T> dataSet, IEnumerable<dynamic> resultSet) where T : class, new()
    {
        IList<T> customResult = (IList<T>)(resultSet.Select(x => BindingProperties(new T(), x)).ToList());
        return customResult;
    }
```

Could anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: `IList<T>` is not covariant or contravariant.

Comment: Please read up on covariance and contravariance then restate your question.

Answer (score -2):

The type `dynamic` in the select expression causes the whole expression to be treated as a dynamic expression, returning a `IEnumerable<dynamic>`

If you explicitly tell C# to use `.Select<dynamic,T>`, you can force the return type to be T and your code will work as expected.

```
    private IList<T> GetResultSetConvertedToList<T>(IList<T> dataSet, IEnumerable<dynamic> resultSet)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        IList<T> customResult = (IList<T>)(resultSet.Select<dynamic, T>(x => BindingProperties(new T(), x)).ToList());
        return customResult;
    }
```

Comment: What does that code even do? Why not just use `.OfType<T>().ToList()`.  You didn't include BindingProperties() either, which looks like something similar to `AutoMapper.Map`.

Comment: I have no idea what the code does.  I just altered the original poster's code to answer the question asked.  If you want to propose `OfType<T>()` as an answer, be my guest but I don't think it is the best answer here because then the Select expression is free to return any type whatsoever, which is filtered to only type T by OfType.  That works fine if the type returned is T but makes for a troubleshooting headache if the type somehow turns into something else, say if the dynamic expression is somehow altered to return a different type.  (OfType would filter the list into an empty enumeramble)

Comment: Oh right.. Didn't fully read the question. It's a bad question at the end of the day. Without more context in what the op wishes to achieve its hard to tell what he wants.